This page isn’t workingpaxintranet.com is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500
good day, after adding secret and access key to the wordpress instance i am getting this error:This page isn’t workingpaxintranet.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
cleared browser history
refreshed the browser page
cleared catche
stopped and restarted my instance
